# Return a function value to main()

Tags: c++, function, file-io, return, function-pointers

I want to return a function value to `main()`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void Cryp(char *str){
    int len = strlen(str);
    int ch;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        ch = str[i];
        ch = ~ch;
        str[i]=ch;
    }
}

char Deco(char *DESTINATION){

  string line,str;
  ifstream myfile(DESTINATION);

  if (myfile.is_open()) 
  {
    while (getline (myfile,line))
    {
      string str(line); 
      str.erase (str.begin()+0, str.end()-9);
      cout<<str; // THIS HAS TO BE RETURNED TO main()!-BUT HOW ??
    }
    myfile.close();
    //remove(DESTINATION);
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return str.c_str();  
}

int Dec(char *SOURCE, char *DESTINATION){
    char Byte;

    FILE *inFile = fopen(SOURCE,"rb");
    FILE *outFile = fopen(DESTINATION,"wb");

    if(inFile==NULL||outFile==NULL){
        if(inFile) fclose(inFile);
        if(outFile) fclose(outFile);
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        while(!feof(inFile)){
            Byte = (char)fgetc(inFile);
            char newString[256];
            sprintf(newString, "%c", Byte);
            Cryp(newString);
            fputs(newString, outFile);
        }
        fclose(inFile);
        Deco(DESTINATION);
    } 

    return 0;
}

main()
{
    Dec("/home/highlander/NetBeansProjects/simple/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/text.dat","/home/highlander/NetBeansProjects/simple/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/text_instant.dat");
    cout<< Deco(char);
}
```

How to pass the `str` value in the function `char Deco(char *DESTINATION)` to `main()`.

Comment: this code doesn't even compile

Answer (score 2):

Just return an `std::string`:

```
std::string Deco(char *DESTINATION){

   // rest of code here

   return str;
}
```

Also, you are missing `int` return specifier for `main` and `Deco(char)` doesn't make sense.

Also, please change the line:

```
string str(line);
```

to

```
str = line;
```

Comment: @highlander141: Please see my update. You are creating a **new** `str` in the inner scope that hides the `str` in the outer scope. You don't want to do that.

Comment: Yeah true, I have did it, how should I call it in `main()` to get that `str` value since I used `cout<< Deco(string);`, though it returns `NULL` !

Comment: @highlander141: Do you mean store the string? `std:string str = Deco(...);` would work.

Comment: @highlander141: `cout<< str;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36856/discussion-between-highlander141-and-jesse-good)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. That gives a dangling pointer to the caller, and is undefined behaviour. Besides that, the return type does not match what you return.

You could save yourself some trouble by returning an `std::string`:

```
std::string Deco(const char *DESTINATION)
{
 ....
 return str;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << Deco("Hello") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @highlander141 well, you were returning `str.c_str(); `, no? So if you are not getting what you expect then there is some other error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char Deco(char *DESTINATION){
```

to

```
string Deco(char *DESTINATION){
```

and then in main you can either assign the return to a string or use it inline

```
string deco = Deco(...
```

or

```
cout<<Deco(...
```

Comment: Thanks,  but its not returning the `str` value, what should I write in main() please let me know...